# How to change content of html.erb from site?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view

On my page I have some description-text, in view.html.erb it looks like

```
<p>"here is some text"</p>
```

below I'd like to make field to input text and after click button description above should be changed. And my problem now is the way I should do this. I thought about creating variable in controller like @text and then in view.html.erb

```
<p><%= @text %></p>
```

but I don't know how to change @text value. Or maybe there is another way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a form that will be altering your model. 
For example, you will need to have a model, called **Post**. That model should have a field, called **text**.

In your controller you will need the following:

```
@text = Post.text
```

In order to change your Post.text you will need to do:

```
<%= form_for @text do |f| %>
  <%= f.text %>
  <%= f.subimt %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So, I'll need only model, without controller?

Comment: you will need both, the model AND the controller. Think of the model as a representation of the object in the system. Like a Post. Think of controller as something that takes your object (Post) and prepares it for the view.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm fairy new in rails, and I don't understand a bit.. Do you mean that in my, for example, HomeController in action where I'd like to change text should I add @text=Post.text and in related view I should call form_for @text etc.. ? Because when I do that, I get 'undefinded method text'

Comment: you need to start with a comprehensive tutorial. I recommend you any of the following videos: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=rails+blog and also this free tutorial by Michael Hartl https://www.railstutorial.org/